# ng2-bootstrap model is coming disabled in ionic2 app

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-bootstrap

I want to show ng2 bootstrap modal in my Ionic2 application. I installed ng2 bootstrap package in my project using the npm command

`npm install ng2-bootstrap --save`

Then imported the package in my project. The modal comes up. But it is in the disabled state. So we wont be able to click on it.
I tried with an example [available in here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals) . That too has the same issue.

Below are the version details of my application:

Ionic Framework: **2.0.0-rc.5**

Ionic Native: **2.2.11**

Ionic App Scripts: **1.0.0**

Angular Core: **2.2.1**

Angular Compiler CLI: **2.2.1**

Node: **6.9.1**

OS Platform: **Windows 8.1**

ng2- bootstrap: **1.3.3**

[image]

I am new to both Ionic2 and Angular2. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code first :

```
 config="{backdrop: false, keyboard: false}"
```

Comment: @Gul config="{backdrop: false}" worked. But how we can implement backdrop feature. Now the modal closes when clicked outside the modal.

Comment: Here ng2-modal api and you can use this features for your application. [ng2-modal api](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals#modal-options)

Comment: `<div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`  trying this code your modals html. You have added backdrop  features

Comment: @Gul I have the same code for the modal in the html page. But still it closes the modal when clicked outside the modal.

Comment: Did you write the two together: {backdrop: false, keyboard: false}. in my opnion keyboard:false is provides this

Comment: @Gul Yes I tried with both together. But still it closes when clicked outside the modal.